# How to call global function from controller class in AngularJs component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

In app.module.js file, import JS file from external lib

```
import 'assets/scripts/admin';
```

with global function:

```
function anonymousAdmin() {
  "use strict";

  implementation();
}
```

Now in app.component.js file have controller with function call:

```
export const AppComponent = {
  controller: class AppComponent {
    $onInit() {
      /* global anonymousAdmin */
      anonymousAdmin();
    }
  }
};
```

Run Webpack/Babel to save all files (ES6) into one file (ES5). Unfortunately i have error in console:

```
ReferenceError: anonymousAdmin is not defined
```

Someone knows how I can call this function in the controller?

Comment: provide your code for `assets/scripts/admin`. may be some namespace/class you are missing?

Comment: There is no namespace/class/scope in file, method is directly in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`anonymousAdmin` is not global function. The file is imported as ES module, and ES modules force strict mode that prevents them from leaking variables to global scope.

It should be explicitly defined as a global:

```
function anonymousAdmin() {...}

window.anonymousAdmin = anonymousAdmin;
```

If the file belongs to third-party module that cannot be directly edited, and considering that Webpack is being used, the latter can be configured to expose a variable from file ES module export with [exports loader](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#global-exports), something like:

```
...
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: require.resolve('assets/scripts/admin'),
      use: 'exports-loader?anonymousAdmin'
    }
  ]
},
...
```

And the function is being imported like:

```
import { anonymousAdmin } from 'assets/scripts/admin';
```

Comment: Thanks, You have right. But add method to window is not a good practice for me. I read about this ES module and add **export** to function in assets file. Now I import method **import {anonymousAdmin} from** in file and it
 works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. You need to have alias for the script.

```
import * as admin from 'assets/scripts/admin';

export const AppComponent = {
  controller: class AppComponent {
    $onInit() {
      /* global anonymousAdmin */
      admin.anonymousAdmin();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Still nothing... Now have error **TypeError: admin.anonymousAdmin is not a function**. Maybe I will add that the whole code is saved to one file by webpack.

Comment: @FpDev The question doesn't mention Webpack anywhere. If you're using Webpack, this should be stated in the question, because it defines this situation.

Comment: sorry my mistake ... I added info to question